# Responsive Design on a Samsung Galaxy S III Mini

Tags: responsive-design, samsung-mobile

I'm busy making an existing site responsive, currently I'm only making it responsive for one resolution so that my sales manager can "sell" the idea of a responsive site to the client. I've run into a problem, I've been assigned the screen size of 480px by 800px, the screen size of a Samsung Galaxy S III Mini.

When testing the responsive design on my computer using responsive design view in firefox or various other online tools, it works fine. However, when I test it on my phone, it displays the correct responsive design but it does not fill the width of the screen. In other words, the screen width is 480 pixels, but nothing on the page actually fills that 480px it only covers about half the screen width and leaves white space on the right.

This is the media query that I'm using:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 480px){
```

Does this have something to do with pixel density or what is causing this problem?

Thanks in advance
Kind Regards
Willem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport">
```

Have you looked into this tag? This changes the way the layout is zoomed/scaled on mobile browsers. You can look at what I found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag . This example shows the problem you seem to be having. The "viewport" tag works in all mobile browsers, as far as I know, but you should check different browsers on the phone if this doesn't help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the zoom problem, however, there is still a large portion of white off to the right of the page, but all the widths have been set to the device width... not sure what is causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same right-side white problem when all widths were working correctly, and solved it by turning off overflow in CSS as follows... This might hide actual content so you will have to test per your situation/layout...

```
html { overflow-x: hidden; }
```